# How can I prove this is a martingale?

Tags: calculus, probability, martingales

If 
$$X_1 = 1,\quad X_{n+1} = 2X_n \text{ or }0 \text{ with equal probability }(P=1/2),$$
with mean: $E|Xn|=1$

How can I prove this is a martingale?

Comment: What is the definition of martingale that you know? Start with the simple conditions in that. Also, $X_{n+1} = 2X_n$ with probability half is imprecise, so make that precise in probabilistic terms if you have to complete the question. (Use a Bernoulli random variable for writing $X_{n+1}$ in terms of $X_{n}$.)

Comment: A process X = {Xn}n>=0 is a martingale relative to the filtration {En}N>= 0 if:
(i) X is adapted, that is, for each n the v.a. Xn is Fn-measurable.
(ii) For all n 0, E|Xn| <Infinity. That is, Xn is L1.
(iii) E (Xn|Fn -1) = Xn -1 for all n>=1.

Comment: This is the definition that I have

Comment: Fine. Now, my question is , which of these is not obvious to you/ are you not able to work out? Surely you must know what filtration is in use?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the filtration but i need to prove a martingale with this conditions. And I don't know how to prove the properties (i) and (iii)

Comment: The filtration is, if not given different, the filtration generated by the process.

Comment: What filtration could be to meet such conditions?

Comment: Look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_filtration

Comment: Okay.l and how can I prove the properties (i) and (iii) that i mentioned before

Comment: Every process is adapted to its natural filtration, so you can ignore the adaptedness. First see if you can write $X_{n+1}$ in terms of $X_n$ *precisely* (because the definition "with probability half" is not precise : you don't know what that means at the level of sample space, for example). From here, integrability should follow at least.

Comment: The probability is only to calculate the mean of Xn+1 but when it comes to showing that it is a martingale I don't think it matters

Comment: Ok read the answer below : the introduction of $M_{n+1}$ was the key point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denotes $M_{n+1}$ the set on which the random variable $X_{n+1}$ is zero. With the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$ you get $$E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)=E(1_{M_{n+1}} \cdot 0|\mathcal{F}_n)+E(1_{M_{n+1}^\complement}\cdot 2X_n|\mathcal{F}_n) = 2X_n\cdot E(1_{M_{n+1}^\complement})=X_n.$$

Comment: Thank you so much